# Add a page break at different levels in a group in report builder

Tags: reportbuilder3.0, page-break

I have 5 different groups within  the Row Groups in Report Builder. I need help  to add pagebreak only after the 2nd group ( in this case at the residentName level and not at the facility level).

Row Groups

1. facility

   2. residentName

      3. room
      4. abbrevdesc

         5. type

Edit: To make things more clear:
Say I have facility = chicagoApartment within which I have various residents say sam, john and sean . Each resident than have their room numbers and multiple description which then has its types.

I want to be able to page break at the resident level so that all the information related to sam stays on the same page instead of expanding to the next.
When I do "page break" inside "group properties" and choose "between each instance of a group".. it cuts off at the facility level but i want the facility to stay chicago and pagebreak at the residentName level.

I hope its more clear now!!

[Row groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfU0z.png)

Comment: please take a look at [ask].  can you share some more details?

Comment: I have added some extra info as per martin's request .. hope it helps. This is my first post:) thx